# How to revoke all group roles from login role

Tags: postgresql

How to revoke all group roles from login role? Is there a way how to do this automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can [`GRANT` / `REVOKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) several roles at once, a single `DO` command with dynamic SQL would be simpler / faster (set-based operations are regularly faster in RDBMS than looping):

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _role regrole := 'my_role';  -- provide valid role name here
   _memberships text := (
      SELECT string_agg(m.roleid::regrole::text, ', ')
      FROM   pg_auth_members m
      WHERE  m.member = _role
      );
BEGIN
   IF _memberships IS NULL THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'No group memberships found for role %.', _role;
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE '%',
      -- EXECUTE
      format('REVOKE %s FROM %s', _memberships, _role);
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

The code is in debug mode. Comment `RAISE NOTICE '%',` and un-comment `EXECUTE` to prime the bomb. Or execute the generated statement manually after checking.

[`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) and [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) require Postgres 9.0 or later.
The object identifier type [`regrole`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) was added with Postgres 9.5

Casting to `regrole` verifies role names on input and double-quotes where necessary when outputting `text` - so no SQL-injection possible.

Effectively executes a command like:

```
REVOKE role_a, role_b FROM my_user;
```

Doesn't break with maliciously formed role names:

```
REVOKE role_a, role_b, "FROM postgres; DELETE * FROM usr; --" FROM my_user;
```

[Note the double quotes around the malicious role name.](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Raises a notice if no role memberships are found.

This revokes *all* memberships in other roles. It's all just roles to Postgres, some have the `LOGIN` privilege ("user roles"), others don't ("group roles").

Comment: Thanks, Erwin, for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think need to query all the roles

```
select usename, rolname 
from pg_user 
join pg_auth_members on (pg_user.usesysid=pg_auth_members.member) 
join pg_roles on (pg_roles.oid=pg_auth_members.roleid)
```

and LOOP through the result to REVOKE rolname FROM usename;